# Issue with Spring RESTful service

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc

When I am adding log4j.jar in my library, Spring RESTful web service is not loading. Console logs:

```
Mar 5, 2012 1:36:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'policy'
Mar 5, 2012 1:36:36 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

It is initializing the servlet but not loading the service after that.

But If I remove log4j.jar, everything works fine. Console logs:

```
Mar 5, 2012 1:32:36 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'policy': initialization started
Mar 5, 2012 1:32:37 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'policy-servlet': startup date [Mon Mar 05 13:32:37 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
```

I do have commons-logging.jar in my library to run Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this question by adding long4j.xml in my classes folder and adding DTD specification to it.
Earlier I was using log4j.properties and log4j.jar was not recognizing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes commons-logging can be used with Spring. I would recommend using slf4j instead.  This is based on nasty personal experience with commons-logging and log4j.

I would recommend using a build tool to clean up your dependencies:

maven: http://maven.apache.org/
or 
gradle: http://gradle.org/

I would also recommend not using commons logging.  It is a personal choice but I use slf4j because of class loading issues I have had with log4j and commons-logging.

Using maven you can exclude commons-logging

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and then include slf4j logging